# Ubuntu on virtual box fails to get on line

Tags: virtualbox

I have a question just occurred to me today. I was using Ubuntu on virtualbox and it was normal. But today it just cannot get online. I tried and the host Win8 can ping the Ubuntu, and Ubuntu can ping host and the wireless router as well. Also Ubuntu can ping 8.8.8.8. I used Bridged Adapter. But I cannot get on line with a web browser, neither the dropbox cannot be connected.

Any good ideas?Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a DNS issue. have you tried pinging google.com or any other web address by name?

Comment: Yes, I tried. And it does not work.

Comment: So definitely a DNS problem. Does `host google.com 8.8.8.8` successfully resolve? How did you configure the network connection of the guest system (DHCP, manual)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just solved it. Simple and easy. Delete /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be a DNS issue. I think you meant /etc/resolv.conf. remember this file will be auto generated by resolvconf program.